# How to compare 3 measures from Current and last year period in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

How do I compare Current and last year period in tableau?

Let's say I have one Dimension names "Prd D" having values like 2014,2015,2016,2017,2018. I have converted "Prd D" with "MY(Prd D)" and now the values are like March 2018,April 2018,March 2019,April 2019,etc.

So, If the current month is April 2019 , I need o get the data for March 2019 and March 2018 .

How do I do that?

Comment: sample data and required output would help to provide solution

Comment: using Last() ,I am getting previous month data i.e March 2019,the same way I just need data for March 2018 in order to compare both .

Answer (score 0):

use `fixed LoD` to get the previous year march data:

```
{ FIXED :SUM(
IF YEAR([Order Date])=2018 and DATENAME('month',[Order Date])="June"
THEN [Sales]
END)
}
```

I used superstore to create the formula, you can replace with your fields

Comment: I have tried this calculation and now getting data for jan2018,feb2018,mar2018,jan2019,feb2019,mar2019    :  if MAX(year([Calculation12]))=MAX(year([Prd D])) then "current ytd"
elseif MAX(year([Calculation12]))-1=MAX(year([Prd D])) and MAX([Prd D])<=DATEADD('year',-1,MAX([Calculation12]))
then "previous ytd"END ! I just want to fetch data for mar2019 and mar2018 in order to compare! window_max works for march2019 but I am not sure about march2018! Tried MID() and window_mediun() but doesn't work.

Comment: why did you take max function just take march month, replace june with march and run the report

Comment: Here,it just computes for [Sales] but I have 4 measures in order to compare!

Comment: create 4 formulas and change measure every time in the formula